# Definition of Banach Algebra in Kesavan text

Tags: functional-analysis

The following snap has been taken from the Kesavan’s Functional Analysis (http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789386279422#otherversion=9788185931876) text.

Here in the definition of Banach Algebra the author didn’t mention the condition that for scalar c and x,y in V $c(xy)=(cx)y=x(cy)$.

Without this condition I doubt whether it forms an algebra at all. Why did the author drop this condition?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be salvaged, at least over the reals.

For positive integers $n$, $n x = x + \ldots + x$ (with $n$ $x$'s).

For negative integers $n$, $n x = - ((-n) x)$ (with $n$ $(-x)$'s.

Then it's easy to show that $c (xy) = (c x) y = x (cy)$ for integers $c$.

For rationals $r = m/n$, $r x$ is the unique $X$ where $m x = n X$.  Again, we'll get $c (xy) = (c x) y = x (c y)$ for rationals.

Now use the continuity of multiplication implied by $\|xy\| \le \|x \| \|y\|$ to get $c (xy) = (cx) y = x (cy)$ for real $c$.

More serious: Banach algebras are usually **not** assumed to have a multiplicative identity.

EDIT: The quaternions are a counterexample for complex scalars.
They can be considered as a $2$-dimensional Hilbert space over the complex numbers, with scalar multiplication by $i$ the same as multiplication on the left by the quaternion $\bf i$, and they are a ring with $\|{\bf 1}\| = 1$ and $\|a b\| \le \|a\| \|b\|$ (in fact $\|a b\| = \|a \| \|b\|$), but of course it is not true that $(ia) b = a (ib)$.

Comment: What about the complex field?